# htaccess rewrite to create friendly urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The following rule works, but it changes the URL in the address bar, which is not intended.

```
RewriteRule ^network/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/network.php?networkUrl=$1 [L]
```

The following rule redirects, the URL stays the same, but all the images, includes in the network.php file become referenced incorrectly...

```
RewriteRule ^network/(.*)$ network.php?networkUrl=$1 [L]
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I suppose you're using relative path in the `network.php` file, you should use absolute paths.

Answer (score 5):

This is because your browser interprets paths as relative.

To solve this reference your images and CSS with absolute paths, i.e. `<img href="image.jpg" />` becomes `<img href="/image.jpg" />`

Same applies for css so

```
<link href="stylesheets/foo.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

becomes

```
<link href="/stylesheets/foo.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

In this way all resources links works as expected when referenced from any depth as `/foo/bar/baz/script.php` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a base href HTML tag in your page could help too:

```
<base href="http://www.domain.com/" />
```

then all your relative images, stylesheets or javascript files will be relative to this base href.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/base